# Focus and Selection Styling listbox items with multiple possible templates

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, styling, itemcontainerstyle

Good afternoon,

I have a listbox that consumes a list of items from a model, Addresses and RAddresses (inherited from Addresses)

Now, previously I have been creating my item templates in the ItemContainerStyle so that I have only my own focus visuals (i.e. no dotted line, no light grey rectangle, etc).  This has worked fine in the past.

I now need two templates, one for each type (Address and RAddress).  I have created these in the ListBox.resources as default templates (example below):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DAL:RAddress}">
```

I also have my listbox's ItemContainerStyle property pointing to the following:

```
    <Style x:Key="AddressContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
```

Previously when the Template was applied to the style, this kept the dotted line and grey rectangle visual from displaying.  However, now they do so and the VisualState settings I have set up do not seem to get applied.

Whole DataTemplate example follows:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DAL:Address}">
<Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="#4C000000" CornerRadius="10" Padding="0" BorderBrush="#00FF0000" BorderThickness="1">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#80000000"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#00FF0000"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#80000000"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups> 
    <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="CheckBox" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Style="{DynamicResource EditGemStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsChecked="{Binding EditMode}"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical" d:LayoutOverrides="Height">
            <Grid x:Name="DisplayGrid" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="7,3,11,3">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="Auto" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="AddressFriendlyName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding AddressFriendlyName}" FontSize="18.667" Style="{DynamicResource Data}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Address1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Address1}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" FontSize="13.333" Style="{DynamicResource Data}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Address2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Address2}" FontSize="13.333" Style="{DynamicResource Data}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Address3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Address3}" FontSize="13.333" Style="{DynamicResource Data}"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="City" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding City}" FontSize="13.333" Style="{DynamicResource Data}"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=", " FontSize="13.333" Style="{DynamicResource Data}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="State" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding State}" Margin="0,0,5,0" FontSize="13.333" Style="{DynamicResource Data}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ZIP" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ZIP}" FontSize="13.333" Style="{DynamicResource Data}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Country" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Country}" FontSize="13.333" Style="{DynamicResource Data}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="EditGrid" Height="Auto" Margin="7,3,11,0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,10,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height">
                    <TextBox x:Name="AddressFriendlyName1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding AddressFriendlyName}" Template="{DynamicResource SnazzyTextBoxTemplate}" Margin="0,2" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="Address4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Address1}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Template="{DynamicResource SnazzyTextBoxTemplate}" Margin="0,2" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="Address5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Address2}" Template="{DynamicResource SnazzyTextBoxTemplate}" Margin="0,2" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="Address6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Address3}" Template="{DynamicResource SnazzyTextBoxTemplate}" Margin="0,2" Foreground="White"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox x:Name="City1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding City}" Template="{DynamicResource SnazzyTextBoxTemplate}" Margin="0,2" Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=", " Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="State1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding State}" Margin="0,2,5,2" Template="{DynamicResource SnazzyTextBoxTemplate}" Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="ZIP1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ZIP}" Template="{DynamicResource SnazzyTextBoxTemplate}" Margin="0,2" Foreground="White"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBox x:Name="Country1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Country}" Template="{DynamicResource SnazzyTextBoxTemplate}" Margin="0,2" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Border>
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Address2}" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter TargetName="Address2" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Address3}" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter TargetName="Address3" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EditMode}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="DisplayGrid" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="EditGrid" Value="Collapsed"/> 
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EditMode}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="DisplayGrid" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="EditGrid" Value="Visible"/> 
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Previously I have tried using a StyleSelector to select between ItemContainerStyles that were created (one for each type).  This caused me to encounter an error "cannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object instance", so I started looking at my present setup.

How can I enforce my own Focus and Selection styling on two separate Item templates hosted in the same ListBox?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to move the specification of the storyboards to the ItemContainerStyle, rather than having them specified in the DataTemplates themselves.  This is more DRY and will lead to less complication.

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DAL:RAddress}">
        <TextBlock>RAddress!</TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DAL:Address}">
        <TextBlock>Address!</TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="IHateDottedBorders" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#80000000"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#00FF0000"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#80000000"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource IHateDottedBorders}" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfAddresses}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: The above style returns the hated "cannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object instance" error when a listbox item is clicked.  I also tried an example you previously gave me with a style consisting of a setter for the Visualstates, but VisualState and VisualStateManager does not have a valid setter.  Any other thoughts?